# Hashtable with format-list cast back to hashtable powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a question about getting into object values in Powershell.

I have a function that returns object | Format-List. Now I assign return value to variable and want to get value from it. Please take a look at below example:

```
$output = @{};
$output.A= "123";
```

function returns: $output | Format-List which gives me:

```
Name  : A
Value : 123
```

In this case I can get value by $output.A, but when it's wrapped into function I do not know how to retrive it

```
function testFunction() {
    $output = @{};
    $output.A= "123";

    return $output | Format-List
}

$result = testFunction
$result.A #gives empty value
```

Anyone can help with this? I do not have access to testFunction, so I cannot modify it.

Comment: The problem is that function is part of external module: https://github.com/ChackDan/Service-Fabric/blob/master/Scripts/ServiceFabricRPHelpers/ServiceFabricRPHelpers.psm1 which returns: return $output  | Format-List; and it's my problem :)

Comment: Well, you can probably iterate the output and extract/parse the info. But I think it's unreliable. That function is really weird. I would simply modify it locally.

Comment: Agree. The author should *not* be using `Format-List` to send output. You want the object data, not a formatted representation of it.

Comment: I created pull request for him with that change. I had the same feeling as you do, but wanted to confirm with others. Thank you guys!

Comment: Thanks again. My pull request was accepted, so issue does not occure any more :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function ConvertFrom-FormatListHashtable {
    param ($InputObject)
    PROCESS {
        $tmp = ($InputObject | out-string).Trim() | ConvertFrom-String
        $tmpCount = ($tmp | gm -MemberType NoteProperty).count
        $i = 1
        do {
            $output = @{}
            $output.Add($tmp.$("p$($i+2)"),$tmp.$("p$($i+5)"))
            $output
            $i=$i+6
        }
        while ($i -lt $tmpCount)
    }
}
```

On your example call

```
ConvertFrom-FormatListHashtable $result

Name                           Value                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                   
A                              123
```